# Java hibernate query issues with order by clause

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hi I am using hibernate query and trying to get results order by the id, but the getResultList function is always returning the result in ascending order even though my query has an order by clause of deviceActivityLogId.

Here is my function

```
public List<DeviceActivityLog> getActivityLogForSysActivityId(int userDeviceRelId,int sysActivityId, int parentId, boolean deleteFlag) {
       String query = "select d from DeviceActivityLog d WHERE d.userDeviceRelId = :userDeviceRelId  and d.deleteFlag = :deleteFlag";
       if (sysActivityId > 0) {
           query += " and d.sysActivityId = :sysActivityId";
       }
       if (parentId >= 0) {
           query += " and d.isParent =:parentId";
       }
       TypedQuery<DeviceActivityLog> deviceQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, DeviceActivityLog.class);
       deviceQuery.setParameter("userDeviceRelId", new UserDeviceRel(userDeviceRelId));
       deviceQuery.setParameter("deleteFlag", deleteFlag);
       if (sysActivityId > 0) {
           deviceQuery.setParameter("sysActivityId", new SysActivity(sysActivityId));
       }
       if (parentId >= 0) {
           deviceQuery.setParameter("parentId", parentId);
       }
       query+=" order by d.deviceActivityLogId desc";

       System.out.println("QUERY: "+query);

       return deviceQuery.getResultList();
   }
```

Can anyone provide a soultion how to get the result list in descending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning a new value to your query String variable AFTER the TypedQuery object has been created from the PREVIOUS value of the query variable.

This is basically equivalent to

```
String message = "Hello";
System.out.println(message);
message += " World";
```

That will obviously print Hello, not Hello World.

It would print Hello World if the code was

```
String message = "Hello";
message += " World";
System.out.println(message);
```

Comment: Ahh. My bad...Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

You change the query string after building the query object.

put your statement

```
 TypedQuery<DeviceActivityLog> deviceQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, DeviceActivityLog.class);
```

at the end (just before `return deviceQuery.getResultList();`) and you should be fine.